# Unable to serialize a nested python object using json.dumps()

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am new to python so sorry about the naive questions. I have a simple code snipper where I try to serialize a python object to a dictionary using json.dumps()

```
import json


class Document:
    uid = "1"
    content = "content1"
    domain = "domain"
    title = "title"


class ASSMSchema:
    requestSource = "unittest"
    documents = []


def entry():
    myObj = ASSMSchema()

    myObj.requestSource = "unittest"

    document1 = Document()
    document1.uid = "1"
    document1.content = "content1"
    document1.domain = "domain"
    document1.title = "title"

    myObj.documents.append(document1)

    print(json.dumps(myObj.__dict__))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    entry()
```

I get the following output when I run the above code

```
{"requestSource": "unittest"}
```

This is not expected however, since it should also seralize the List of "Document" objects. Appreciate your answers. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class definition of `ASSMSchema` defines the *class members* `documents` and `requestSource`. These are not attributes of a single instance of this class, but shared between all instances. When you are running `myObj.requestSource = "unittest"`, you are defining a member variable on the instance `myObj`. This member is actually reflected in the output of `json.dumps`, whereas the class members (like `documents`) are not.

For further reading, see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

Depending on the complexity and desired maintainability of your program, there are multiple approaches to archieve your desired behaviour. Firstly, you have to fix the mistake in both class definitions. To define a class with instance variables instead of class variables, do something like this:

```py
class Foo:
    # class variables go here

    def __init__(self, field1, field2):
        # This method is called when you write Foo(field1, field2)

        # these are instance variables
        self.field1 = field1
        self.field2 = field2
```

If you want to dump this class as JSON, you can simply use the trick with `__dict__`: `print(json.dumps(Foo(1,2).__dict__))` will output something like `{ "field1": 1, "field2": 2 }`.

In your case, there is the `documents` member though, which is not JSON serializable by default. Therefore, you must handle this separately as well. You could write an encoder for your `ASSMSchema` (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3768975/13679671) for more info on that). It could be implemented roughly like this:

```py
from json import JSONEncoder

class ASSMSchemaEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return {
            "requestSource": o.requestSource,
            # Convert the list of Document objects to a list of dict
            "documents": [d.__dict__ for d in o.documents]
        }
```

Now, when serializing an instance of `ASSMSchema`, this implemention is used and the `documents` member is replaced with a list of dictionaires (which can be serialized by the default encoder). Note, that you have to specify this encoder when calling `json.dumps`, see the linked thread above.

Comment: Thanks for the response niklas! Any suggestion on how I can modify the code to get the desired output?

Comment: The answer should now have everything you need, further resources are linked, that can help you, if you want to read more.

Comment: Thanks a lot again! This worked for me, appreciate your help.